# Changing values defined in styles at runtime?

Tags: android, xml, styles, runtime

```
<style name="TitleBarTheme_lvl2Enable" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">150dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBarBG</item>
</style>
```

This current style is being applied as the theme and I am currently trying to change the window title size at runtime and haven't found any posts on here explaining now, if anyone can shed some light on this that would be awesome!

Comment: Why don't you create one more style? And use it as per your requirement.

Comment: I've tried using recreate() after setTheme() and having another style that changes the window title size but all it seems to do is flash the screen, momentarily change the theme for a moment and then it changes right back to the old theme.

Comment: can you post the code?